# Difference in performance of two SELECTs and a SELECT plus JOIN

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, rdbms

I searched through the web to find out how a JDBC call is transmitted to the data base management system. What I want to know is, whether a JDBC call produces network traffic in order to communicate with the DBMS, even if the data base is local?

I need to argue why two separate SQL `SELECT` statements are more expensive than a single one with a `JOIN`.

Comment: It depends on the DBMS I'd say, but you can always have a look at e.g. the jTDS driver for SQL Server or the Postgres driver. Both are open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is using a JDBC Driver.

[image]

> The driver is platform-dependent as it makes use of ODBC which in turn
>   depends on native libraries of the underlying operating system the JVM
>   is running upon. Also, use of this driver leads to other installation
>   dependencies; for example, ODBC must be installed on the computer
>   having the driver and the database must support an ODBC driver. The
>   use of this driver is discouraged if the alternative of a pure-Java
>   driver is available. The other implication is that any application
>   using a type 1 driver is non-portable given the binding between the
>   driver and platform. This technology isn't suitable for a
>   high-transaction environment. Type 1 drivers also don't support the
>   complete Java command set and are limited by the functionality of the
>   ODBC driver.

Check out more on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver)

> I need to argue why two separeat SQL SELECT statements are more
>   expensive than a SQL single one with JOIN.

I would say that it may depend upon on the scenario. Although it is said that `JOIN` will almost always be better performance. But still you may find certain scenarios(although few) where `SELECT` statements are preferred.

In most cases we can say that `Join` will usually outperform multiple single SELECTS as it enables the database to do a lot of optimizations since by using JOIN the overhead is reduced and it knows how many tables it has to scan.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I should update my question. What I want to know is, whether the JDBC relies on TCP/IP in order to communicate with the DBMS?
I need to argue why two separeat SQL SELECT statements are more expensive than a SQL single one with JOIN. If JDBC relies on TCP, then it may overload the connection by issuing the doubled amount of SQL statements.

Comment: I dont think so that JDBC relies completely on TCP/IP in order to communicate with the DBMS. It can use HTTP as well!!!

Comment: But does the traffic passes the network interface card, even for each kind of driver?

Comment: And regarding your second query that two seperate SQL SELECT statements are more expensive than a SQL single JOIN. I would say that is dependent on the scenario ie, in which scenario you are using the two. At times even joins are slow as compared to two seperate SELECT statements

Comment: Hope this helps http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs51/techoverview/jdbc.html

Answer (score 1):

In any scenario, the costs of passing query to the database server are negligible compared to the costs of calculating the results of your query/queries and passing them back to your application.

As @RahulTripathi mentioned, depending on the scenario, either of the latest consideration can determine which way you would want to go. Normally, the rule of thumb is to let database do what it's good at: selection, projection and joins.

Although in some cases you might indeed want to do two separate selects instead. For example, if you join tables in a way that was not anticipated by the database designer (on a column that is not a foreign key and/or to a column which is not a primary key or not even indexed) and the database is "very busy", you might be better of with 2 selects.

If you join a large table to a small table that has a lot of fields, you might want to split your query in two, especially if the second table is not changing a lot. In that case you can go even further: you can cache the records from the second table and only query the first table.

But, as I said above, you need a good reason to not use a single SELECT query.